# How to find Magnitude of transfer function

Tags: filter

I am trying to read a paper by Butterworth on his filter.
There is a term called filter factor which is said to be the ratio between output emf by input emf.But i am not able to understand the mathematical expression.I want to know weather is it the transfer function as if i write the transfer function it comes out to be 
$$ (1)/(SCR +s^2LC +1) $$

which does not match with his expression which is 
$$ 1/( 1+ x^4)^{1/2}$$

I also presume that it can be the magnitude of transfer function.
In that case can you give me hint on how to go about the problem of finding the magnitude.

I am giving the link to the paper.
Its in the second page.
[link](http://www2.ee.ufpe.br/codec/paper%20BUTTERWORTH.pdf)

Comment: Your link is not working. It's giving me a "404: file not found" page.

Comment: Yes, i am referring to equation-1,which is for FIg.1.I think filter factor refers to the magnitude of the transfer function.Can anyone please guide me on how to get the magnitude of a transfer function.

Comment: Let \$s\rightarrow j\omega\$, and derive the amplitude frequency response by taking the magnitude of the resulting complex term.

Comment: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091107181525AAytHxc in this article he is substuting s = jw and then rationalising and what i thought is  say substitute $$ s = j\omega$$ in $$H(s)$$ and then substitute $$ s = -j\omega$$ in $$H(s)$$ and multiply both.Is that correct

Comment: @ANUPAM BISH: the upper case \$S\$ in your formula should be a lower case \$s\$, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following information can help to clarify the problem:

1) The expression **SQRT[1/(1+x^4)** is a second-order function we WANT to realize because this is a function which has a "maximally flat" magnitude response. That means: If compared with all other possible 2nd-order functions the magnitude deviates as less a s possible from its value at x=0 (which in this case is "1"). Note that for a frequency-dependent filter the variable x is identical to a frequency variable w=2*Pi*f which is normalized to the 3dB-cutoff frequency wc. Therefore we have **x=w/wc**.

2.) We can REALIZE only filter functions with lumped elements which can comply with the general second-order lowpass function **H(s)=Ao/(1+a*s+b*s²)**. If we calculate the zeros of the denominator (poles of the whole function H) we find that **a=1/(wp*Qp)** and **b=1/(wp²)**. Both pole parameters wp and Qp are definded using the pole location of the pole pair in the complex s-domain.

3.) Now, the results from 1.) and 2) are equalized (what we want = what we can realize). For this purpose, we use the squares of both functions. After some mathematical manipulations we arrive at the expression:

**H(s)=Ao/(1+0.7071x+x²)**  with **x=w/wc**

4.) This is the general transfer function for a 2nd-order **Butterworth lowpass** with DC gain Ao. There are different methods (topologies) for realizing this function as an electronic circuit. One simple solution (passive) is to use a suitable RLC combination (as in your example with Ao=1). To find the corresponding expressions (parts values) you have nothing to do than to compare the corresponding coefficients of both functions (from the circuit and the given H(s) for the desired 3dB-frequency wc).

Answer (score 0):

These old articles often use terms which have gone out of fashion making them more challenging to read.

Indeed the *Filter factor* is an different word for the transfer function H(s).

The reason why Butterworth uses

$$ 1/{( 1+ x^4)^{1/2}}$$

is because he want to make a transfer function H(s) "look like"" this function because that determines the position of the poles which determines the behavior of the filter.

Comment: This means this relation is not related to the figure-1.He is trying to model the filter in the future using that equation.Am I right ?